# Loading different pages under different tabs in flask application

Tags: python, flask, twitter-bootstrap

I want to render 3 different pages/views under each tabs.

```
user.html
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs"  data-tabs="tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">edit profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">change password</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">change email</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <p>User profile edit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        {% include 'flask_user/change_password.html' %}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        {% include 'change_email.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

and the view is as below:

```
@app.route('/profile/<int:agent_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_profile(agent_id):
form = ChangePasswordForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    change_password()
return render_template('user.html', form=form)
```

Currently Its send only one form which is for #tab2. but if I send all the 3 forms, userProfileForm(), changeUserEmailForm() and ChangePasswordForm()
then It will be complex while handling POST request.

Is there any other way to make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to open new tabs when users click on links?

Comment: Its like opening tabs. Kindly look into this example.    http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_menu_list-inline&stacked=h

Comment: Sorry, that example doesn't do anything in my browser! (chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to POST back to the same route for the three forms. Set-up three different routes to handle the POST backs and set each form's action attribute to the appropriate route.